# Is the Zariski topology equipped with Eisenstein's metric an analytic submanifold?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, differential-geometry, differential-topology

Using $M=(C(\mathbb{R}),T_z)$ with the norm $(x,y) \to \log(\partial_x+\partial_y)$, we can easily define a derivative using distributions.  I was wondering: Does this make $M$ an analytic manifold sitting inside $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{R}$?

Edit: The derivative I refer to maps an $f \in C(\mathbb{R})$ to the spectrum of it's Eisenstein matrix: $f \to Sp(M(f))$.

I guess my question is: Does this space have a countable basis with respect to that derivative? This would then make it analytic, correct?

Comment: Needs more explanation.

Comment: Thanks, I added some detail.

Comment: Needs more:  Zariski topology, analytic manifold.  To me (a non-expert, presumably missing something) it seems clearly false: Zariski topology is not Hausdorff, but an analytic manifold is.